# Bad operand type for Binary operator "*"

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors, binary

Bad operand type for Binary operator "*"

I am getting the error during compilation as Bad operand type of Binary operator saying that: first type: int second type: int[] and i have to use this logic only. Following is a part of my program

```
public static int pmean(int[] ar){
    int[][] a = new int[ar.length][ar.length];
    int k=0;
    int min=0;
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<ar.length;i++){
        k=i+1;
        for(int j=0;j<ar.length;j++){
            a[i][j]= (k * a[j]);//error at this line
            k++;
            if(k==ar.length+1)
                k=1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You cannot multiply an `int` and an `int[]` in Java like that.

Comment: Any method to do.Does it mean that the whole set of integers that i need to multiply should be kept in another array?

Comment: @Torrtuga - your edit has been reversed, as you can see. If you solved your problem, great - post an answer explaining how, and move on. But don't edit both your question's title and content to 'answer solved' - that doesn't help anything or anybody.

Answer (score 3):

`a[i][j]= (k * a[j]);` a[j] is an array, you probably meant a[i][j]

Comment: Any method to do.Does it mean that the whole set of integers that i need to multiply should be kept in another array?

Comment: replace `a[i][j]= (k * a[j]);` with `a[i][j]= (k * a[i][j]);`

Comment: @torrtuga You just changed your code to read ar[j]. That would compile. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I edited the error line. Please see. It is actually a different array ar[] being multiplied by k and stored in a[][]

Comment: @Torrtuga ar[j] is an int, not an int[], and the edit should not throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

a is a two dimensional array so a[j] is an array. You cant multiple and int with an array